# Passing array of single precision floats to GLSL shader using glBindImageTexture

Tags: glsl

I want to pass a 2D array of single precision floats to a GLSL shader.  I am trying to use glBindImageTexture for this purpose.

Before the main OpenGL render loop I define the texture and fill it with random values using

```
glGenTextures(1,@imagetexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,imagetexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
setlength(arrayvalues,imwidth*imheight);
for loop:=0 to imwidth*imheight-1 do arrayvalues[loop]:=random;
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, imwidth, imheight, 0, GL_R32F, GL_FLOAT, arrayvalues);
setlength(arrayvalues,0);
glBindImageTexture( 0,                  //unit
                    imagetexture,       //texture
                    0,                  //level
                    false,              //layered
                    0,                  //layer
                    GL_READ_WRITE,      //access
                    GL_R32F);           //format
```

The shader code is the bare minimum for testing

```
#version 430

layout (binding=0,r32f) uniform image2D my_image;

void main()
{
    float f = imageLoad( my_image, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy) ).r;
    //f = 0.5;
    gl_FragColor=vec4(f,f,f,1.0);
}
```

The code all runs, but the output is always black?  Any ideas what I have missed here?

The same surrounding code works fine for other shaders that do not rely on glBindImageTexture so I am assuming it is all OK.

If I unremark the f = 0.5 then I get a grey image, so it all seems OK otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Working code.  The issue was me not originally calling glBindTexture before glBIndImageTexture and also using GL_R32F rather than GL_RED.

```
glGenTextures(1,@imagetexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,imagetexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
setlength(arrayvalues,imwidth*imheight);
for loop:=0 to imwidth*imheight-1 do arrayvalues[loop]:=random;
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, imwidth, imheight, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, arrayvalues);
setlength(arrayvalues,0);
glBindImageTexture( 0,                  //unit
                    imagetexture,       //texture
                    0,                  //level
                    false,              //layered
                    0,                  //layer
                    GL_READ_WRITE,      //access
                    GL_R32F);           //format
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `glGenTextures` to create a texture name, that texture is considered unused until you first bind it. And I *don't* mean `glBindImageTexture`; I mean `glBindTexture`.

`glBindImageTexture` does not bind the texture to a texture unit; it binds the texture to an image unit for use as an image. It does not bind it to the context for manipulation purposes. So calls to functions like `glTexParameter` don't care about what you've bound to image units.

You have to bind the texture with `glBindTexture`, then establish its information like the size and so forth, and *after that*, bind it for use as an image.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  It was an issue with needing glBindTexture.  Also I have a GL_R32F rather than a GL_RED.  I have updated the code to the working version in the original post as it may help someone else in the future.

Comment: OK, I answered my own question.